# AutoHotKey run program on any key

Tags: batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'd like to run a program when any key is pressed with AutoHotKey

Something like:

```
AnyKey::Run, D:\my\program\to\run\on\any\key.bat
```

EDIT2:
This code is working perfectly:

```
 #InstallKeybdHook

SetTimer, AnyKeyPressed, 100

AnyKeyPressed:
    if( A_TimeIdlePhysical < 100 ){
        Run, D:\my\program\to\run\on\any\key.bat
}

^!p::pause
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: What do you want to achieve with such a functionality?

Comment: I want to launch the script when I leave my computer so if someone uses it my webcam takes a picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
#InstallKeybdHook  ; this MUST be called at the start of your script

AnyKeyPressed() ; returns a 1 if any keyboard key is pressed, else returns 0
{
    if( A_TimeIdlePhysical < 25 )
        return 1

return 0
}
```

Note this function will return 1 if any key is pressed OR being held down, so change your code appropriately.

What happens is; the `#InstallKeybdHook` will change the behaviour of `A_TimeIdlePhysical` to only look for keyboard events.

Comment: So if I replace return 1 by `Run, D:\my\program\to\run\on\any\key.bat` it will run on all keyboard output?
Also if I don't put `#InstallKeybdHook` will it work with mouse too?

Comment: Yes, it will run your program continuously( many many times per second ) when a button is pressed. I doubt you want that. You probably want it to run it only ONCE. So change your code that it will do that. Removing `#InstallKeybdHook` will return `A_TimeIdlePhysical` to its original function. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm

Comment: I copy-pasted exactly your code into my ahk script but I replaced `return 1` by `MsgBox test` and it doesn't work whatever key I press

Comment: @pocpoc47 The code is correct. Did you call the function? Copy pasting the code wont magically make it work.

Comment: How should I call it? I tried just putting `AnyKeyPressed()` after } but it doesn't work either
See my EDIT

Comment: @pocpoc47  Example of a function call: `myFucntion()` in an empty line, i suggest you ask a new question if you have problems with that.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check `A_TimeIdlePhysical` periodically, not just once on script start:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SetTimer, CheckActivity, 100
Exit

CheckActivity:
    if(A_TimeIdlePhysical < 100) {
        Run, myNastyPictureMaker.bat
        ExitApp
    }
return
```

You can use `SetTimer` for recurring tasks. The script stops when the first activity was detected; otherwise, it would take a picture every 100 ms (or whatever timeout you set).

P.S: I hope you only want to use such a script on your private PC and not some publically available computer...

Comment: thank you that was the trick. And don't worry it's on my personal computer more a prank than anything else :)

Comment: well both the answers solved my problem so I didn't know which one choose :s

Answer (score 1):

Use Input, AnyKey, L1 to wait for any key to be pressed. L1 means after one key was pressed, without a [end] key required. You can check the content of AnyKey, but don't really need to.

Comment: Seems like what I need but I don't really get the syntax.. How do I use this to run my program? Sorry if it's a stupid question I'm new to Ahk

Comment: The is a nice hack, but unfortunately  it does not work for keys that do not produce any text output. Same goes for fanuch's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a list of known keys might work?

```
keys = ``1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./
Loop Parse, keys
Run, D:\my\program\to\run\on\any\key.bat
return
```

This is what comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Persistent
#InstallKeyBDHook
SetTimer, WaitingForKey, 100

Return

WaitingForKey:

    Input, LogChar, B I L1 V
    LogWord := LogWord . LogChar
        ToolTip, % LogWord
    ;Run, D:\my\program\to\run\on\any\key.bat
    LogWord:=
    Return


^!p::pause
```