# How can I interrupt a loop by pressing "any" key in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I currently have a script that repeatedly presses the left mouse button, until the script is interrupted.  To start and stop the script the ALT+2 is pressed.  How can I have it start with ALT+2 but stop by pressing any key?

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 3
!2::  ; ALT+2 hotkey 
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 1
if KeepWinZRunning  
{
    KeepWinZRunning := false  ; 
    return  ; 
}

; Otherwise:
KeepWinZRunning := true
Loop
{
    ToolTip, Press ALT+2 again to stop.
    Sleep 100
    Send, {VK01 down}{VK01 up}
    Sleep 100
    if not KeepWinZRunning  

        break  ; Break out of this loop.

}
KeepWinZRunning := false  ; Reset in preparation for the next press of this hotkey.
ToolTip
return

ExitApp
F12::ExitApp
```

Comment: 1) Use [timers](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) instead of *endless* loops, they provide better support for (pseudo-) multithreading. 2) The [Input command](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Input.htm) is what you're looking for. Have a good look at the options though.

Comment: MCL is right.  A timer also gives you the option to run a thread simultaneously or even break out of a timer thread.  MCL's helped me with that one before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, here's an example using `Timers` and `Input`:

```
endKeys={enter}{tab}{LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}

!2::
    SetTimer, SendSomething, 200
    Input, pressedKey, I L1, % endKeys
    SetTimer, SendSomething, Off
return

SendSomething:
    Send, {VK01 down}{VK01 up}
return
```

You may have to complete the list of `endkeys`, depending on your keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979909/autohotkey-run-program-on-any-key).  Here is a direct quote.  You should look at the original post for details (I can't take credit for it), but here is the snippet:

```
#InstallKeybdHook  ; this MUST be called at the start of your script

AnyKeyPressed() ; returns a 1 if any keyboard key is pressed, else returns 0
{
    if( A_TimeIdlePhysical < 25 )
        return 1

return 0
}
```

Comment: That won't work in most cases. `A_TimeIdlePhysical` will be reset by mouse events, too. Consequentially, the loop will stop whenever the mouse is moved; and not just whenever a key is pressed.

Comment: @MCL - so, are you saying the the keybdhook treats the mouse like a keyboard key?

Comment: @MCL A_TimeIdlePhysical won't be reset, because of `#InstallKeybdHook`

Comment: You're both absolutely right. I never knew that *If only one hook is installed, only its type of physical input affects A_TimeIdlePhysical*.